# Keyword not supported while using postgresql with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am encountering an issue with my database update. I set everything fine, I am creating my migrations, it is working but when I want to update my database or even remove my migration to edit something, I get this error

```shell
➜  ProjectDotNET $ dotnet ef database update                
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: host:127.0.0.1;port (Parameter 'keyword')
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetProperty(String keyword)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Keyword not supported: host:127.0.0.1;port (Parameter 'keyword')
```

I'm looking everywhere, I did a simple connection string as I can find it [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/npgsql/standard/) but nothing changed.

Here is my `csproj` file

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.6">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

My connection string in my `appsettings.json`

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Host=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=dotnetDB;User Id=rootapp;Password=[a password];Pooling=true;"
  }
}
```

I also tried `Server` instead of `Host` in the String, nothing changed

And I my `StartUp.cs` file

```c#
// ...
services.AddDbContext<MangasCollectionContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
// ...
```

Regarding the error message, I'm assuming that it may not be my code and my nuget packages seems to be compatible.

Thank you for your help

Comment: With `Server` keyword you get same exception? You try without `Pooling`?

Comment: Try removing the package reference to "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design"

Comment: Check here if you have missed anything: https://dinindu.medium.com/asp-net-core-entity-framework-core-with-postgresql-31f3939c93c4

Comment: The connection string that Npgsql is complaining about (`host:127.0.0.1;port`) doesn't seem to correspond to what you have in appsetings.json - make sure your application is loading the connection string correctly.

Comment: Thank you for all your comment. I tried without Pooling first, and also with Server with the same result. I think the root cause was due to the fact that it took the development version of the appsettings I never touch... So even with my modification, it didn't took it well. Although, `Server` was the right keyword. Thank you all and @dinindu for your link !